# How to avoid fluctuating value of a token against currency

Tags: tokens

How can you use a smart contract to account for currency-originated payments (e.g. mortgage) without asking the homeowner to risk the fluctuating value of a token by holding it?  I know Everex has the principle of currency to currency exchange so your token is only held for the transaction only, which seems ideal, are there other ways around the token valuation problem for recurring payments?

Comment: You might find what you're looking for by searching here for other questions on pegging a token against another security/currency and exchange rate oracles.